# Spiral Number pattern in java

Tags: java

I need to create these patterns in java according to how-many  numbers the user enters:
like this if user enters 3:

```
1  2  3   ------------>
8  9  4   |------->   |
7  6  5   <-----------|
```

if user enters 4:

```
 1   2   3  4
12  13  14  5
11  16  15  6
10   9   8  7
```

if user enters 5:

```
 1   2   3   4  5
16  17  18  19  6
15  24  25  20  7
14  23  22  21  8
13  12  11  10  9
```

and so on..

Comment: is it an array/just print

Comment: Interesting question, but please share your attempted code.

Comment: I can print so-many simple patterns using nested for loop but it is critical so I do not understand how to start and what to even try.

Comment: I posted the question here because I can get more hints from other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found Solution. Like This

```
//you can change Input No Here.
    int INPUT = 5;

    //statics for direction type 
    final int LEFT = 1;
    final int DOWN = 2;
    final int RIGHT = 3;
    final int UP = 4;

    //Grid Array
    int[][] patt = new int[INPUT][INPUT];

    //initial position 
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    //initial direction
    int Direction = LEFT;

    //Master Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < INPUT * INPUT; i++) {

        int temp = i + 1;

        //Checking boundaries
        if (y > INPUT - 1) {
            Direction = DOWN;
            x++;
            y--;
            i--;
            continue;
        } else if (x > INPUT - 1) {
            Direction = RIGHT;
            x--;
            y--;
            i--;
            continue;
        } else if (y < 0) {
            Direction = UP;
            y++;
            x--;
            i--;
            continue;
        }else if (x < 0) {
            Direction = LEFT;
            y++;
            x++;
            i--;
            continue;
        }

        if (patt[x][y] == 0) {
            patt[x][y] = temp;
        } else {
            if (Direction == LEFT) {
                Direction = DOWN;
                y--;
            } else if (Direction == DOWN) {
                Direction = RIGHT;
                x--;
            } else if (Direction == RIGHT) {
                Direction = UP;
                y++;
            } else {
                Direction = LEFT;
                x++;
            }
            i--;
        }

        switch (Direction) {
        case LEFT:
            y++;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            x++;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            y--;
            break;
        case UP:
            x--;
            break;
        }
    }// Master Loop Ends

    // Print Grid Array
    for (int i = 0; i < INPUT; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < INPUT; k++)
            if (patt[i][k] <= 9)
                System.out.print(" "+patt[i][k] + " ");
            else
                System.out.print(patt[i][k] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I got a great hint from @lakshman's Suggestion. Thanks to @lakshman.

Answer (score 1):

One direction you may look into:

First create a empty 2D array to store the result

The pattern I can observe is, for example to fill a table of dimension 5, start from the upper left corner, fill 5 number to right, then change direction clockwise, fill 4 numbers, then change direction clockwise, fill 4 numbers, change direction, fill 3, change direction fill 3....

The "number of digits to fill" is having the pattern of n, n-1, n-1, n-2, n-2..... 1, 1

(I believe there are other pattern that is easier but I don't think this is hard that is not implementable)

Another way is, similar to what I do above: keep a variable to represent the direction, start from top-left corner, keep on filling number until you hit 1) boundary or 2) an array entry that is already filled with number.  Then turn your direction clockwise.  Repeat until fill up all numbers.